# Extract few letters from the column (values are in string)

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to extract last three letters of 'CLASS' column and last 6 letters depending on the rows. In SQL Developer.

I have the following table-

```
ROW_NO    CLASS
   1      BLUE_ALL
   2      GREEN_ALL_SET             
   3      WHITE_ALL
   4      RED_ALL_SET
   5      YELLOW_ALL
   6      PURPLE_ALL_SET
```

I need to create third column called CATEGORY as show below

```
ROW_NO    CLASS            CATEGORY
   1      BLUE_ALL         ALL
   2      GREEN_ALL_SET    ALL_SET             
   3      WHITE_ALL        ALL
   4      RED_ALL_SET      ALL_SET
   5      YELLOW_ALL       ALL
   6      PURPLE_ALL_SET   ALL_SET
```

Thanks

I tried using combination of SUBSTR and INSTR functions

Comment: Feel free to share what have you tried with `substr` and `instr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have only `_ALL_SET` and `_SET` suffixes, so take last 7 or 3 chars:

```
select row_no, class,
  substr(class, case when class like '%\_ALL\_SET' escape '\' then -7 else -3 end) category
from tablename
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83ea0/1).
Results:

```
ROW_NO  CLASS               CATEGORY
1       BLUE_ALL            ALL
2       GREEN_ALL_SET       ALL_SET
3       WHITE_ALL           ALL
4       RED_ALL_SET         ALL_SET
5       YELLOW_ALL          ALL
6       PURPLE_ALL_SET      ALL_SET
```

Answer (score 2):

At least based on the sample data you provided, it seems that in every case you want to extract everything AFTER the first underscore.

If so:

```
select row_no, class, substr(class, instr(class, '_') + 1) as category
from   your_table
order  by row_no  --  if needed
;
```

**DEMO**:

```
with
  your_table (row_no, class) as (
    select 1, 'BLUE_ALL'       from dual union all
    select 2, 'GREEN_ALL_SET'  from dual union all             
    select 3, 'WHITE_ALL'      from dual union all
    select 4, 'RED_ALL_SET'    from dual union all
    select 5, 'YELLOW_ALL'     from dual union all
    select 6, 'PURPLE_ALL_SET' from dual
  )
select row_no, class, substr(class, instr(class, '_') + 1) as category
from   your_table
order  by row_no  --  if needed
;

    ROW_NO CLASS          CATEGORY      
---------- -------------- --------------
         1 BLUE_ALL       ALL           
         2 GREEN_ALL_SET  ALL_SET       
         3 WHITE_ALL      ALL           
         4 RED_ALL_SET    ALL_SET       
         5 YELLOW_ALL     ALL           
         6 PURPLE_ALL_SET ALL_SET
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be applying `regexp_substr()` analytic function and `listagg()` concatenation consecutively :

```
with t2 as
(
 Select Regexp_Substr(class, '[^_]+',1,level+1) as str, row_no, class, level as lvl
   From t
Connect By level <= Regexp_Count(class, '_')
and prior row_no = row_no and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
Select row_no, class, listagg(str, '_') within group ( order by lvl ) as category
  From t2
 Group By row_no, class;

ROW_NO  CLASS           CATEGORY
------  -------------   --------
1       BLUE_ALL        ALL
2       GREEN_ALL_SET   ALL_SET
3       WHITE_ALL       ALL
4       RED_ALL_SET     ALL_SET
5       YELLOW_ALL      ALL
6       PURPLE_ALL_SET  ALL_SET
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b1da44ecdc9b4cd93168453e6de1ba17)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like conditional logic:

```
select (case when class like '%\_%\_%' then substr(class, -6)
             else substr(class, -3)
        end)
```

Comment: Rare slip from Gordon :) This won't work because `_` is also a `LIKE` wildcard (matches a single character). Escape the underscore using `... when class like '%\_%\_%' escape '\' then ...`. Also, the first `substr` should be `substr(class, -7)`. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4aeff4/22).